# IntelliJ IDEA - TS1128: Declaration or statement expected

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

I downloaded a sample angular 2 project from git and opened it with IntelliJ then in Terminal I "run npm install".

Now when I open app.components.ts file I see above error

[image]

Additional info

npm -v ==> 4.0.5

tsc -v ==> 2.1.4

node -v ===> typescript 6.9.4

and in settings I have

[image]

Comment: what is your `nodeJS` version ? is it *1.4* ??

Comment: In your settings, your Typescript compiler version is 1.4, not 2.1.4... I think you also have to use Intellij EAP, is it v14 ?

Comment: solved.Thank you.my intellij version was 14.1.4 and Typescript was 1.4.I upgrade my intellij to 16.3.2 and worked it.